# What is the passive of 'the teacher teaches us English'?

Tags: passive-voice

Active - The teacher teaches us English.

Passive - English is taught us by the teacher?

It doesn't sound correct but is it??

Comment: Per my comment to @Skip's answer, your passive is fine. Just a bit starchy.

Answer (score 8):

English is taught to us by the teacher.

Comment: OR *we are taught English by the teacher.*

Comment: @StoneyB: Dunno about you, but I can't say I have any problem with OP's original "passive" version in the first place. So far as I'm concerned the preposition **to** is entirely optional there, and if anything including it is just a half-baked attempt to change a relatively formal construction into something more "natural" that simply doesn't work very well. Your more radical restructuring is a much better way to achieve that.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree we don't need the *to*. Restructuring may be better, but may not if  the context is something like *Spanish we study online, but English is taught us by a teacher*. Great Mother English is mostly pretty good about giving us different tools for different situations.

Comment: @StoneyB Okay, I need a little grammar lesson here I suppose ;) I must conclude I am wrong if both you and Fumble are on the opposite side, but the OP's original phrasing without the *to* is, to my ear, completely ungrammatical. "Guidance is given us by our parents?" "Toys are given us by Santa Claus?" I need the *to* in all of these cases to have a sentence that sounds right to me. What am I missing?

Comment: @WendiKidd  +1 I'm with you and equally curious to know. I cannot imagine that sentence without a preposition.

Comment: @WendiKidd It's perfectly ordinary to my ear, but I'm an old man, and steeped from childhood in Late Victorian-Edwardian literature. Grammatically it's the usual transform of "Santa Claus gives us toys": passivize the verb and its object, front-and-flip-em, turn the Agent into a pp and move it to the end, and you're left with bare *us* in the middle.

Comment: @WendiKidd: Ditto. As [this NGram shows](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=taught+us+by&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctaught%20us%20by%3B%2Cc0), the "prepositionless" form was much more common a century or two ago, but you can see that ***to*** has increasingly been gaining currency over recent decades. Actually, that pattern is even more marked if you check for ***given*** rather than ***taught***, but even on that one ***to*** has only *just* become more common overall.

Comment: ...for that reason I've neither upvoted nor downvoted this answer. So far as I'm concerned it's correct to say if you *do* want a preposition, it should be ***to***. But there's no good reason to insist on a preposition in the first place, so it's something of a "loaded question".

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm concerned the passive form of **"The teacher teaches us English"** is **"We are taught English by the teacher"**.

While the passive form **"English is taught to us by the teacher "** is actually that of the active **" The teacher teaches English to us"**

I can't say that I agree with FumbleFingers concerning the optionality of the **to** preposition in the passive form omission of which sounds ungrammatical to my non-native ear. To those who are learning English as a foreign language I don't recommend such omissions.

Comment: The *to*-less construction sounds somewhat dated/formal, but not ungrammatical at all to me, and I'm not a native speaker of English either. Further, both  passive forms of the given active are valid since *teach* is ditransitive.

Answer (score 1):

In that case, two objects are given. In which case there may be two passive forms. Both are correct.

1. We are taught English by the teacher.
2. English is taught us by the teacher.

Comment: Please take extra care to get the basic grammar, and spelling correct in answers. Make sure you use capital letters in the right places. You will get downvotes for lack of care, despite this being a correct answer.

Comment: it's ok.actually i didn't care about explanation just i kept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The teacher teaches us English = The teacher teaches English to us.

Both the sentences, which are in the active voice, are grammatical.

They can be changed into the passive either starting the sentence with the indirect object or the direct object as follows:

We are taught English by the teacher.

English is taught to us by the teacher.

However, it's far more common and natural to use the verb teach in the structure "teach + somebody +something" than in the structure "teach + something + to + somebody".

So the sentences #1 and 3 are more idiomatic than the sentences #2 and 4.